# Given $2$ sets containing n elements (label one $x$, one $y$), is there always an nth term polynomial that passes through all the points $(x, y)$?

Tags: polynomials

Sorry if this is worded badly. What I'm trying to ask is more like, given $2$ sets with $n$ elements each and creating coordinates by taking all the numbers in set 1 and all the corresponding numbers in set $2$, is there always an $nth$ term polynomial which passes through all of these points? And if so, does it extend into the complex plane?

Comment: Do you mean there are exactly $n$ distinct points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$?

Comment: I think so, I'll edit the post when possible to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: More questions: 1. Do you mean an $n^{\textrm{th}}$ degree polynomial? 2. Do you mean for all of the $x_i$ to be distinct? 3. Do you mean for all of the $y_i$ to be distinct? If the $x_i$ needn't be distinct, then your polynomial equation may have to be of the form $P(x,y) = 0$ instead of $y=P(x)$, because no polynomial function has a graph passing through the points $(0,1)$, $(0,0)$, and $(1,0)$

Comment: $Nth$ degree, I said it like this every time irl, idk what happened when I wrote it down. All the $x$ are not necessarily distinct, and same for all $y$

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that they are both distinct, I was distracted while I wrote that.

Answer (score 1):

You will only need a degree $n-1$ polynomial to do this. See this question:

[why we need a polynomial of degree at most n-1 not n when doing interpolation with n data points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816934/why-we-need-a-polynomial-of-degree-at-most-n-1-not-n-when-doing-interpolation-wi)

Not sure what you mean by "Does it extend into the complex plane?".

Comment: Sure, polynomials with real coefficients (or complex, for that matter), extend naturally to functions on the complex plane...

Comment: Oh, is that all he meant? I couldn't imagine what was intended. +1 for you, @paulgarrett

Comment: I'd wager that that is indeed what was intended... perhaps without thinking about it too much, or, perhaps, being naive about such things.

Comment: Or, now that I think further, it could be that the "extension" issue was about allowing the x's and y's to be complex? Still, your answer is good, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This also works with complex numbers.
Label the points as $\{ (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \cdots, (x_n, y_n) \}$

Now, consider $f$:

$$ f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( y_j \times \dfrac{\displaystyle \prod_{i \in [n]\setminus\{j\}}  (x-x_i)}
{\displaystyle \prod_{i \in [n]\setminus\{j\}} (x_j-x_i)} \right) $$

$f(x)$ is a $(n-1)$-degree polynomial.
Try to evaluate $f(x_i)$ for some $i$, and you'll notice how it turns out to be $y_i$.

This is also the only $(n-1)$-degree polynomial that satisfies this property.

Comment: Thanks, I was kinda in disagreement with my maths teacher lol, I’ll show her this. Beautiful answer btw, thanks.